# complexity of the interior point method with inequality constraints

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, quadratic-programming

Assume I have an optimization problem:
$$
\min x^TQx
$$
$$
\text{Subject to } Ax \leq b 
$$
$$
x \geq 0
$$
$A$ is an $m\times n$ matrix and $x$ is an vector with $n$ elements. I know that it needs $\sqrt{n}\ln(1/\epsilon)$ iterations to converges to an $\epsilon-$acccurate solution. But according to my experience, the converge time also relates to the number of constraints.

> **My question:** How does the number of constraints $m$ influence the convergence time?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry, I have a problem that is listed above. Q is a positive definite matrix. I want to use the interior point method to solve this problem. I want to ask how can I calculate the complexity and how the complexity is related to the number of constraints (m).